# Web wysiwyg editor with live output to html div

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a web based wysiwyg editor (like tinyMCE)
That will output the content of the editor to an html div (much like the ditor on this very site).

Is there any existing (open-source) product that can or can be made to do this?

Comment: Can't you somehow utilize tinyMCE's [onKeyUp](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onKeyUp) event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use any editor, watch after it's textarea, detect change, get content, and display it in your page.

```
$(".tinymce textarea").change(function(){
    $("#preview").html($(".tinymce textarea").val());
}
```